# Merge two CSVs with different data Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I need to create a CSV file with data from two different CSV's that have been exported from systems currently in place. I am familiar with creating, reading, and writing CSV files in ruby but this one is stumping me.

**google.csv**

```
Email_address,First_name,Last_name
samling@duneland.k12.in.us,Suzanne,Amling
```

**asm.csv**

```
first_name,last_name,email_address
SUZANNE,AMLING,SUZANNE.AMLING@DUNELAND.K12.IN.US
```

I need to replace the emails from the **asm.csv** with the emails from the **google.csv** that correspond to the correct first and last name. I am not sure how to match the first and last name in both csvs to replace them and create a new one. How can I achieve this?

I attempted an answer from SO already but it is only returning the first and last name.

```
require 'CSV'

hs = %w{ First_name Last_name email_address person_id person_number sis_username location_id }

CSV.open('skyward.csv', "wb") do |csv|
  csv << hs
  CSV.foreach('asm.csv', headers: true) do { |row| << row.values_at(*hs) }
  CSV.foreach('google.csv', headers: true) do { |row| << row.values_at(*hs) }
end
```

Comment: You will garner more interest if you simplify your example and make it complete (e.g., no `...`).  In `asm.csv` you have far too many fields for an example. I suggest you include only `"first_name`, `last_name`, `email_address` and one or two others. Also it's sufficient to have, say, just three lines after the header line in `asm.csv`, and perhaps four lines after the header line in `google.csv` (three that match lines in `asm.csv` and one other).  This is fine for an exercise but in real life you'd have to deal with two people with the same name.

Comment: If my answer reflects a correct understanding of your question feel free to edit your question to use my example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create two CSV files.

```
asm=<<_
Email_address,First_name,Last_name
avance@duneland.k12.in.us,Abigail,Vance
astafford@duneland.k12.in.us,Adrienne,Stafford
AFath@duneland.k12.in.us,Alysha,Fath
_

google=<<_
first_name,middle_name,last_name,email_address
ALBERT,,EINSTEIN,al@princeton.edu
ADRIENNE,X,STAFFORD,adrienne@yahoo.com
ALYSHA,M,FATH,afath@noodle.com
ABIGAIL,R,VANCE,abby@gmail.com
_

ASM_FNAME="asm.csv"
GOOGLE_FNAME="google.csv"

File.write(ASM_FNAME, asm)
  #=> 159
File.write(GOOGLE_FNAME, google)
  #=> 182
```

Read `GOOGLE_FNAME` and create a hash.

```
require 'csv'

h = CSV.foreach(GOOGLE_FNAME, headers:true).with_object({}) do |line,h|
  h[[line['first_name'].downcase, line['last_name'].downcase]] = line['email_address']
end
  #=> {["albert", "einstein"]=>"al@princeton.edu",
  #    ["adrienne", "stafford"]=>"adrienne@yahoo.com",
  #    ["alysha", "fath"]=>"afath@noodle.com",
  #    ["abigail", "vance"]=>"abby@gmail.com"}
```

Now read `ASM_FNAME` and use the hash `h` to replace the email addresses.

```
CSV.foreach(ASM_FNAME, headers:true).map do |line|
  [h[[line['First_name'].downcase, line['Last_name'].downcase ]],
    line['First_name'], line['Last_name']].join(',')
end
  #=> ["abby@gmail.com,Abigail,Vance",
  #    "adrienne@yahoo.com,Adrienne,Stafford",
  #    "afath@noodle.com,Alysha,Fath"]
```